# how to access immediate unknown key in object

Tags: javascript

how to access immediate unknown key in object. in pic "367:sl" is dynamic key and i want to access cptyName value which is in "367:sl". Thanks in advance

[image: pic]

Comment: is this dynamic key `367:sl` the only key in `quotes` object? or there might be a lot of them? if so, do you need to get the first one?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If your dynamic key is the only key in `quotes` object, you can get the first key and then access value with:

```
var firstKey = Object.keys(quotes)[0];
var cptyName = quotes[firstKey].cptyName;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mGZpa/

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through the object.

```
var quotes = {
    '367:sl': 'cptyname'
}

for(var i in quotes) {
    alert(quotes[i]);
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LPK3L/)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer of @Michael Radionov, a more slick definition of the `firstKey` variable would be to replace:
`var firstKey = Object.keys(quotes)[0];`

with the more slick:
`const [firstKey] = Object.keys(quotes);`
using [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#array_destructuring)

---

As correctly noted by @Unmitigated, it can be done even faster by using `Object.values` directly.
Full code (updated for 2022):

```
//Objects
const quotes1 = {
    "367:sl": { //unkown key
        cptyName: "bank1"
    }
};

const quotes2 = {
    "999:sl": { //unknown key
        cptyName: "bank2"
    }
};

// Arrow function to get the (first) value of unknown Object key  
getCptyName = quotes => Object.values(quotes)[0].cptyName;


console.log(getCptyName(quotes1)); //bank1
console.log(getCptyName(quotes2)); //bank2
```

[Here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lazpetr/c0shm8f3/6/)

Comment: `Object.values(quotes)[0].cptyName` suffices.