# Compare value within nested object

Tags: javascript, object, compare, key

So I've been trying to find a solution to this for a little while with no luck.

```
const nameTest = 'testName';
const test = {
   RANDOM_ONE: {
       NAME: 'testName',
       SOMETHING: {...}
   },
   RANDOM_TWO: {
       NAME: 'Name',
       SOMETHING: {...}
   }
}
```

Is there any simple, easy way where I can compare the nameTest and the NAME key without knowing what the RANDOM_X is in order to access NAME?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to access immediate unknown key in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302398/how-to-access-immediate-unknown-key-in-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the array of all the keys. Then loop through the array to check the property:

```js
const nameTest = 'testName';
const test = {
   RANDOM_ONE: {
       NAME: 'testName',
       SOMETHING: {}
   },
   RANDOM_TWO: {
       NAME: 'Name',
       SOMETHING: {}
   }
}
let testKeys = Object.keys(test);
testKeys.forEach(function(k){
  console.log(test[k].NAME == nameTest);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for ... in loop:

```
for (let key in test) {
  if (test[key].NAME === nameTest) {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope we know that 2 levels down into test is your object. You could write a function, to compare the name key.

```
function compare(obj, text){
 for(let x in obj){
   if(obj.x.name == text) return true;
   else ;
 }
}
```

Then call the function with your object and the string.

```
let a = compare(test, nameTest);
```

Note: this would compare the object to only ascertain if it contains the nameTest string.

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj= test.filter(el){
    if(el.NAME==nameTest)
    {
        return el;
    }
 }
var x= obj!=null?true:false;
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).

> The find method executes the callback function once for each index of
>   the array until it finds one where callback returns a true value. If
>   such an element is found, find immediately returns the value of that
>   element. Otherwise, find returns undefined.

So it is more memory efficient, than looping over the whole object with [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), because find returns immediately if the callback function finds the value. Breaking the loop of forEach is impossible. In the documentation:

> There is no way to stop or break a forEach() loop other than by
>   throwing an exception. If you need such behavior, the forEach() method
>   is the wrong tool.

**1. If you want to get the whole object**

```js
var nameTest = 'testName';
var test = {
   RANDOM_ONE: {
       NAME: 'testName',
       SOMETHING: {}
   },
   RANDOM_TWO: {
       NAME: 'Name',
       SOMETHING: {}
   }
};

function getObjectByNameProperty(object, property) {
    var objectKey = Object.keys(object)
        .find(key => object[key].NAME === property);
    return object[objectKey];
}

var object = getObjectByNameProperty(test, nameTest);
console.log(object);
```

**2. If you just want to test if the object has the given name value**

```js
var nameTest = 'testName';
var test = {
   RANDOM_ONE: {
       NAME: 'testName',
       SOMETHING: {}
   },
   RANDOM_TWO: {
       NAME: 'Name',
       SOMETHING: {}
   }
};

function doesObjectHaveGivenName(object, nameValue) {
    var objectKey = Object.keys(object)
        .find(key => object[key].NAME === nameValue);
    return objectKey ? true : false;
}

console.log( doesObjectHaveGivenName(test, nameTest) );
```