# How can I fetch data from Firebase into my React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please, I am very new to React.js and having this challenge of fetching dating from Firebase to populate this. I want to be able to fetch a single properties and not all of them - eg (title, body and price).

useFetch is a custom hook I created inside the project to handle the fetch from firebase.

What am I not getting right here please?

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import useFetch from '../UseFetch';
import '../courseDetails/CourseDetails.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

import React from 'react'

const CourseDetails = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const { data:details, isLoading } = useFetch('https://tutorialwebsite-460f1-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/courses.json');
    console.log(details);
    return (
        <div className="course-detail">
            <h2>{ id }</h2>
            <div>
                <p>{details.description}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CourseDetails
```

Here's the object loaded from the API:

```
{
  "-MaebRkqKfjLG8heBbSu": {
    "body": "qwerqwer",
    "description": "wqerqwetqwe",
    "imageUrl": "wdfwerw",
    "price": "werqwertwer",
    "title": "title 1"
  }
}
```

How can I access the `description`?

Comment: How does your useFetch look like?

Comment: let me update the question to include the usefetch.

Comment: You cannot fetch just a single property, unless the server supports that. You have to fetch the entire JSON, then parse it and extract the data you want. Please also mention how exactly your code fails, because I'm not sure what the issue is exactly. What do you see in that paragraph? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Your data is `[]` initially, but you're loading an object (`{...}`). Also, you should use conditional rendering based on `isLoading` when you try to render `details.description` since that's probably causing an "can't read x of undefined" error

Comment: @ChrisG on the CourseDetail page. I want to be able to extract just the body, price and imageUrl to display on that page.

Comment: What's the actual problem? Do you know how to read properties from an object or how to destruct an object?

Comment: @jabaa The actual problem is I want to fetch some data from the firebase data I am using on the course/detail page.

Comment: You're already fetching data. The question is unclear for me. You're asking how to fetch data and you posted code that fetches data. What's the actual question?

Comment: @jabaa how can I display it on the page if that's the right word. After consoling, I am getting an object. The problem is how to display it on the page.

Comment: So your actual question is how to access a property in an object? Like in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors I don't know if there is a duplicate or if this is too basic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232938/discussion-between-dennis-and-jabaa).

Comment: Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This question should be answered in every JavaScript beginners tutorial and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). Another way to access properties is destructuring assignment (also described in beginners tutorials and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment))

Comment: The key here is how to access the only property of arbitrary name in the data. What you need is `Object.values(data)[0].description`

Comment: Found a bunch of dupes, here's the most similar one: [how to access immediate unknown key in object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24302398/how-to-access-immediate-unknown-key-in-object)

Comment: What is `-MaebRkqKfjLG8heBbSu`? Where does it come from? Does it change? Is it always the only property in the response? `Object.values(data)[0].description` works if `-MaebRkqKfjLG8heBbSu` is always the first/only property. If the key doesn't change you can use `data['-MaebRkqKfjLG8heBbSu'].description`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your response but I was able to solve my problem. So what I did was changed into a used fake json api instead of firebase I was initially using. Then I was able to dynamically route to a specific page based of the unique id after fetching the data from firebase and then used conditional rendering to output the data on the page. However, I would have loved to know how to do this using using firebase.

```
const CourseDetails = () => {
    const { id } = useParams();
    const { data:details, isLoading } = useFetch('http://localhost:8000/courses/' + id);
    console.log(details)

        return (
        <div className="course-detail">
                {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
                {details && <div>{details.body}</div> }

        </div>
    )
}

export default CourseDetails
```